# Changing Label.Value from different UserForm

Tags: vba, excel

I have two Forms and I want to change `Label.Value` on one form, but do it from another form. How can I do it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `UserForm1.Label1.Caption = "myLabel"`? call this from the other form

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Thanks :) Sorry for this stupid question